# magento one order with multiple invoices per vendor

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am facing the following issue:

Suppose there are Two vendors A and B.  Vendor A has the **product X** and Vendor B has **product Y**.

If a buyer purchases both product from Vendors A and B, it creates one order.

Then how we can create different Ship and Invoice for the vendors for same order; or you can also say Main order has sub order according to vendor product?

Answer (score 1):

You can ship and invoice the products of A nd B separatelly by doing a partial invoice/shipment with built-in methods of Magento. Just select the products of vendor A and invoce/ship them.

Comment: how can generate partial invoice from rest api in magento-2.1?